# get union type with `keyof typeof`

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How can I get the union or enum type from a `typeof` type?

Example

```
const myConfs: { [k: string]: (myArg: { name: string }) => string } = {
  'Hello': ({ name }) => `World from ${name}`,
  'Goodbye': ({ name }) => `World from ${name}`,
};
type MyKeys = keyof typeof myConfs;


// I want this to trow an error
const key: MyKeys = 'hello';
```

I have tried just removing the type definition of `myConfs` and that works, but that breaks the type definement of the callback argument within the value field on `myConfs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a factory function. This let's you solve your problem and avoids code duplication.

```
function createConfs<T extends { [k: string]: (myArg: { name: string }) => string }>(confs: T) : T{
    return confs
}

const myConfs = createConfs({
  'Hello': ({ name }) => `World from ${name}`,
  'Goodbye': ({ name }) => `World from ${name}`,
})

type MyKeys = keyof typeof myConfs;

const key: MyKeys = 'hello';
// Type '"hello"' is not assignable to type '"Hello" | "Goodbye"'. Did you mean '"Hello"'?(2820)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-dev.20220609#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAigJwKYEMYYMJIgDOAPACrIYAeuEAJkcgN7IDaA1gFzJExpwQA5gF1uACgC2ATwCCaQdxYQsEjN178hyAL4BKZAF4AfDz4DBOo2KiEi3MvvtNgyV8kwwwaFDYjFg2sDAvrzI0gR+jAaomDj4tmLOrgDkABIYADYZCMniSioYOvrGyAAGAOoIaBl0yCBoCBLIACRMyqrapQA0LsjJAOIICHQARlIYuciJyO2FeoYmFVU1dQ1NrbOdPXpBMFIADoUAslIA0hhSUcjsFwggyHuHd2FSEcQA3EHAAPTfyACSyAA7lgIDAHgALOCMGAIB4NIHIUGUNANNDBJChG5Sbgnc6XQx9CGZbLJd5AA)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of solving this. You are setting your keys to be any string. Use mapped type to limit it to what your set needs to be:

```
const keys = <const>["Hello", "Goodbye"];

type MyConfs = {
  [K in typeof keys[number]]: (myArg: { name: K }) => string;
};

const myConfs: MyConfs = {
  Hello: ({ name }) => `World from ${name}`,
  Goodbye: ({ name }) => `World from ${name}`
};

// I want this to trow an error
const key: keyof MyConfs = "hello";
```